# How to get the numbers from 50 - 100 with the numbers 2, 0, 2, 4

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-property

All I need is 56-59, 69, 73, 75- 77, 79, 86, 90-94, 99.  I've done the rest but I would love to hear other solutions.

Rules:

1. Use any of the following operations: basic operations (+ - x /), to the power of (^), Square root, factorial, double factorial, concatenation (e.g. 42 is acceptable).
2. You can write the numbers in any order but you may only use each number once.

Good Luck!

---

In a comment, the OP said, “Repeating decimals are not allowed as an answer (e.g. 92.22222 ≠ 92). But you may use repeating decimals as part of an equation (don't know any case).”

Comment: Is triple factorial allowed?

Comment: Triple factorial is not allowed

Comment: Okay. I found an answer for 56. Should I post a partial answer?

Comment: What is a partial answer? Any answer is fine

Comment: Found one for 92

Comment: A partial answer is an answer that is not complete but has some parts of the puzzle.

Comment: Post the answer please

Comment: Guys should I post my answers for the ones I have?

Comment: I think so. Then other people probable won't give answers for those you already have.

Comment: @Marius How would you even notate that?

Comment: @WOWOW... Hence my confusion :)

Comment: You cant make 41 unless you have something like 42 - 0!

Comment: Anyone do any progress yet?

Comment: Got 79 and 99. Check my answer

Comment: Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Are decimal points allowed?  Are repeating decimals allowed?

Comment: Repeating decimals are not allowed as an answer (e.g. 92.22222 ≠ 92). But you may use repeating decimals as part of an equation (don't know any case).

Comment: I need 9 more numbers. 57, 69, 71, 73, 75, 76, 77, 91, 93

Comment: I got 7 of 9 numbers you needed.

Comment: @bob are subfactorials allowed?

Comment: @bob And is the rising factorial allowed?

Answer (score 7):

Work in progress

> $58 = (4+0!)! / 2 - 2$
>  $59 = ((4+0!)! - 2) / 2$
>  $86 = (42 + 0!) \times 2$
>  $94 = ((4 + 2)!! - 0! ) \times 2$

Comment: Thanks, did you say you had one for 56?

Comment: I said it's work in progress :). I hope I can find one for most of them

Comment: @bob that was me, not him

Comment: Have you found one yet?

Comment: Nope. that's all I have. I quit. It's too hard.

Answer (score 5):

Partial Answer:

> $56 = ((2 + 0!)!)!! + 2 \times 4$
>  $58 = ((2 + 0!)!)!! + 4!! + 2$ or $(4!!)^2 - (2 + 0!)!$
>  $69 = \frac{0!}{.\bar{2} - .2} + 4! $
>  $79 = (4!! + 0!)^2 - 2$ or $79 = (2 + 0!)^4 - 2$
>  $90 = 42 + ((2 + 0!)!)!!$
>  $99 = (4!! + 2)^2 - 0!$

Comment: are you sure? I get 58 on this.

Comment: I got 56. There might be a mistake though.

Comment: This is correct, the answer is 56

Comment: ok. my bad...I think

Comment: Can you explain 56 please

Comment: @Topwizard29Thegamer 0 factorial is 1, 3 factorial is 6, 6 double factorial is 48.

Comment: @bob I got 90 using the double factorial of 6.

Comment: Wow, congrats for getting 90!

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> $\large 57=((2+0!)!)!!+\frac{\sqrt{4}}{.\bar2}$
>
>  $\large 69=((4!)-(0!)) \times \sqrt{ \frac{2}{.\bar2} }$
>
>  $\large 71=4! \times \sqrt{\frac{2}{.\bar2}} -0!$
>
>  $\large 73=4! \times \sqrt{\frac{2}{.\bar2}} +0!$
>
>  $\large 75=((4!)+(0!)) \times \sqrt{ \frac{2}{.\bar2} }$
>
>  $\large 76=2 \times (40-2)$
>
>  $\large 91=\frac{\sqrt{4}}{.\bar2-.2} + 0!$

Comment: It's just 77 and 93 remaining, right?

Comment: @WOWOW I believe you are right.  Hopefully someone will get them.

Comment: I'm not good at math lol. I'm quite happy that I even got to write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Someone mentioned only 77 and 93 were remaining.

Here is 77:

> $77 = ((4!!)!!)*.2 + .2 + 0$
>  or
>  $77 = (((4!!)!!) + 2 - 0!) * .2$

And here is 93:

> $93 = \frac{4!}{.\bar2} - (\frac{0!}{.2})!!$

Comment: +1 I especially like your first solution for 77.  Almost all other answers posted so far use 0 factorial.

Comment: Congratulations on getting 93.